# Remove multiple trailing slashes in root using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rule in my htaccess file to remove any extra trailing slashes from a url, this works on sub-directories with any more than 1 trailing slash. However it doesn't work on the root; which i need it to do.

For example.

http://www.example.com/test//// Redirects to http://www.example.com/test/

http://www.example.com/// Needs to redirect to http://www.example.com

Any ideas on what i need to add?. Cheers.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(?:/){2,}$
RewriteRule . %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the current code...

Comment: Try cleaning your browser caches.

Answer (score 9):

For removing multiple slashes **anywhere** in `REQUEST_URI` this rule works best:

```
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

It takes advantage of the fact that **`mod_rewrite` engine itself converts all multiple forward slashes to a single slash in the `RewriteRule` pattern**. We use `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` to make sure original `REQUEST_URI` contains multiple slashes.

Here `[^?]*//` matches 2 `//` before matching query string since `[^?]` matches anything except `?`. This will allow `//` in query string.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: After searching many many hours, this is the one that finally worked. Thanks mate!

Comment: Nice. However, I had to use `$0` instead of `/$0` in the `RewriteRule`. Otherwise, `/foo///bar///` was redirected to `//foo/bar/`.

Comment: `$0` will not have leading `/` if used in .htaccess but it will have a leading `/` if used in Apache config/vhost config.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)//+$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am not recommend this as it will generate more then one redirection on more then two slash

Comment: No, because `//+` is for `more then one slash`

Answer (score 1):

You htaccess works great as you can test on below link

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

[image: Working]

So you need to make sure you test either with a Chrome Incognito window or using like below

```
curl -v http://example.com////
```

I usually prefer curl as I know it will give a fresh response from the server always

Answer (score 0):

You just need two rule to match two different pattern

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:/){2,}$
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(?:/){2,}$
RewriteRule . %1/ [R=301,L]
```